# How to disconnect from OpenConnect?

Tags: networking, vpn, openconnect, background-process

I command something like this : `sudo openconnect -b serverName` for **connect** to **vpn** but when i want to **disconnect** it , the process does not **kill** and its **alive** in **background**.

I used these commands for disconnecting but they did not work for me in **ubuntu** 20.10 :

1-`sudo killall openconnect`

2-**use** `ctrl` + `c`

Comment: There is no such version of Ubuntu as 20. There is a 20.10 and a 20.04

Comment: Yeah i update it

Comment: Answer for cleanly exiting [found on UNIX stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/725171)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use something more powerful like `kill -9`.

First find out PID number like so:

```bsh
pgrep openconnect
12345
```

After that, kill the process with: `sudo kill -9 12345`.

One liner can also be used

```bsh
kill -9 `pgrep openconnect`
```

Comment: Thanks , but i faced with `bash: kill: (12345) - Operation not permitted`

Comment: I used `sudo` and it works , thanks i vote up it and if it i dont have better answer i will accept it.

Comment: This seems to kill it, but it doesn't seem to clean up iptabes maybe? The next time you connect to openconnect it warns: "RTNETLINK answers: File exists" Is there maybe a cleaner way?

Answer (score 0):

IF you have more than one and want to script it you can run this:

```
pgrep openconnect | while read line ; do sudo kill -9 $line ; done
```